# Find missing rows between three related tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have three tables:

**Person**

```
person_id
-------------
10001
10002
10003
10004
```

**Dates**

```
date_type      date
-------------- -----------------------
PUBLIC_HOLIDAY 2020-04-10 00:00:00.000
PUBLIC_HOLIDAY 2020-04-13 00:00:00.000
```

**Absence**

```
person_id date                    absence_type
--------- ----------------------- ------------
10001     2020-04-10 00:00:00.000 HOLIDAY
10001     2020-04-13 00:00:00.000 HOLIDAY
10002     2020-04-10 00:00:00.000 HOLIDAY
10003     2020-04-13 00:00:00.000 HOLIDAY
```

I need to find all of the `person_id`'s in the **Person** table and the `date`'s from the **Dates** table  who have not booked any absence matching the following criteria:

- Dates.date_type = 'PUBLIC_HOLIDAY'
- Absence.absence_type = 'HOLIDAY'

Basically, I need to find the people and the dates which are public holidays they have not booked an absence for as holiday.

Comment: Please provide sample data

Comment: @SureshGajera Sample data added

Comment: Desired output would also be good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this below logic-

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=81911ec8c7618098b481291c751326ae)

```
SELECT Person.person_id,Dates.dat,ISNULL(Absence.dat, 'Not Bokked')
FROM Dates
CROSS JOIN Person
LEFT JOIN Absence ON Person.person_id = Absence.person_id AND Dates.dat = Absence.dat 
WHERE Dates.date_type = 'PUBLIC_HOLIDAY'
```

If you wants only information with not booked, just simply add below line to the script-

```
AND Absence.dat IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks! This is the simplest query of the answers. I like it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below query. I have tested this in SQL Server 2014.

```sql
CREATE TABLE #Person(person_id INT)

INSERT INTO #person
values
(10001),
(10002),
(10003),
(10004);

CREATE TABLE #Dates (date_Type VARCHAR(50), [datevalue] datetime)

INSERT INTO #Dates
VALUES
('PUBLIC_HOLIDAY','2020-04-10 00:00:00.000'),
('PUBLIC_HOLIDAY','2020-04-13 00:00:00.000');

CREATE TABLE #Absence (person_id int, datevalue datetime, absence_type VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO #Absence
VALUES
(10001,'2020-04-10 00:00:00.000','HOLIDAY'),
(10001,'2020-04-13 00:00:00.000','HOLIDAY'),
(10002,'2020-04-10 00:00:00.000','HOLIDAY'),
(10003,'2020-04-13 00:00:00.000','HOLIDAY');

SELECT p.person_id, od.datevalue
FROM #Person AS p
CROSS JOIN (SELECT * FROM #Dates WHERE date_type ='PUBLIC_HOLIDAY') AS od
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT 1 FROM 
#Absence AS a
INNER JOIN #Dates AS d
ON a.datevalue = d.datevalue
WHERE a.absence_type = 'Holiday' AND d.date_type = 'PUBLIC_HOLIDAY'
AND a.person_id = p.person_id and d.datevalue = od.datevalue)
```

Below is the resultset:

```
+-----------+-------------------------+
| person_id |        datevalue        |
+-----------+-------------------------+
|     10003 | 2020-04-10 00:00:00.000 |
|     10004 | 2020-04-10 00:00:00.000 |
|     10002 | 2020-04-13 00:00:00.000 |
|     10004 | 2020-04-13 00:00:00.000 |
+-----------+-------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want a `cross join` to generate all combinations of persons and dates, and then `not exists` to filter on those that do not exist in the `absence` table:

```
select p.*, d.*
from person p
cross join dates d
where 
    d.date_type = 'PUBLIC_HOLIDAY'
    and not exists (
        select 1 
        from absence a 
        where a.person_id = p.person_id and a.date = d.date and a.absence_type = 'HOLIDAY'
    )
```

Comment: From the OP question, We should only consider the dates in the absence table, which are public holidays also.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select distinct person_id from absence a
where absence_type = 'HOLIDAY'
and not exists (select 1 from dates
                where date = a.date 
                and date_type = 'PUBLIC_HOLIDAY')
union all
select person_id from person p
where not exists ( select 1 from absence
                   where p.person_id = person_id)
```

If you want to have them with dates, use below query:

```
select person_id, date from absence a
where absence_type = 'HOLIDAY'
and not exists (select 1 from dates
                where date = a.date 
                and date_type = 'PUBLIC_HOLIDAY')
union all
-- in person table we don;t have any dates
select person_id, null from person p
where not exists ( select 1 from absence
                   where p.person_id = person_id)
```

Comment: the absence table will not have all persons. In the example 10004 is missing in absence table.